# Is there a way of one reading data from multiple tables that are related using multiple where clause?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have three tables namely classes, bookings and users. I want to read users bookings that where approved.

but it is giving me an error of Column not found even though all the columns are there

the table's structures are as follows

[image: Classes table]

[image: Bookings table]

[image: Users table]

and the error im getting
[image]

and this is my query
[image]

Comment: Well, the query does not include the bookings table in the from clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it using laravel Join from the Laravel docs. The query is as follows and is working as i expected.

```
 $myCourses = Classes::join('bookings', 'classes.id', '=', 'bookings.course_id')
        ->select('classes.*')
        ->where('bookings.customer_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)
        ->where('bookings.status', '=', 'Approved')
        ->get();
```

Went through the laravel docs on their site and came across that.
Link to the solution source
https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Can you show me your models? Is there any reason why you aren't using relationships?

You are missing the magic of eloquent

Using a hasMany bookings on your courses model and a belongsTo on your booking model would solve your issue.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: i have used eloquent relations. Class hasMany Bookings.....Bookings Belong to Class.........User haMany Bookings.....Bookings belong Users